# Permission dependent behavior

Tags: vimrc, autocmd, wrapping

I would like to set some options for all things I will read but not modify. 
That is special settings for read-only files (and files in vim view mode).

Particularly I'm interested in `setlocal wrap` for read-only files.

---

I know that for special type files (like quickfix) I can use [autocmd](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2843/how-to-automatically-set-wrapping-for-quickfix-window).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, you can use an `BufEnter` autocommand, that checks, whether the file is modifiable. Something like this should work (untested):

```
augroup ReadOnly
    au!
    au BufEnter *  if (!&modifiable || &ro) | setl wrap | endif
augroup END
```

Comment: yeah, works, briliant! I will learn more about autocmd, thanks! what is difference between !&modifiable and &ro ?

Comment: For windows that appear without entering like quickfix BufRead could be better choice.
The list of autocommands: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html

Comment: This answer does not distinguish file buffers from buffers created by `:help` or `NERDTree`; potentially breaking these latter.

Comment: well, first of all, that was not asked for. Second of all, you don't need the VimEnter autocommand for that. Rather check the buftype option.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt The other commenter, Mesco, is in fact issuing the very same warning, although stated in a different wording. I experienced unintended side effects from `BufEnter * if (!&modifiable || &ro)` with the before mentioned plugins first hand, albeit with a different payload (not `wrap`). Thanks for down-voting, by the way.

Comment: @SergeStroobandt The problem is, The VimEnter autocommand is not helping you in any way and is the wrong solution to whatever problem you are trying to solve. You did not mention what problem you are actually trying to solve, so it would be advisable first mentioning what problem you are facing. By the way, setting `wrap` only for modifiable buffers seems a bit strange.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I was using your solution during some time for setting specific Markdown highlighting when using Vim `view`. See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/314184/39845) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39836959/2192488). It took me quite some time to figure out that your `au` conditional was causing odd behaviour with `NERDTree` and `:help`. Mesco's `BufRead` resolves the NERDTree problems, but not the `:help` issues.

Answer (score -1):

## Without breaking `:help`, nor `NERDTree`

The problem with `BufEnter * if (!&modifiable || &ro)` or `BufRead * if (!&modifiable || &ro)` is that these do not distinguish file buffers from buffers created by `:help` or `NERDTree`; potentially breaking these latter.

Hence, below solution rather employs [`VimEnter`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#VimEnter) for creating for example a Vim-based Markdown [viewer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/314184/39845) or [pager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39836959/2192488).

```
augroup ReadOnly
    au!
    au VimEnter * if (!&modifiable || &ro) | setl wrap | endif
augroup END
```